# Angular 4 Http Json deserialization and generics

Tags: angular, typescript, generics, deserialization

I have an api that returns a json object like the one below:

```
{
    "name": "testing",
    "theme": "something"
    "themeProperties": {}
}
```

The type of object that `themeProperties` has will change depending on the value of `theme`. I am trying to define these types like this:

```
export class Config<T> {
    public name: string;
    public theme: string;
    public themeProperties: T
}


export class Style1Props extends Config<Style1Props> {


    public fooProp1: number;
    public fooProp2: boolean
}

export class Style2Props implements Config<Style2Props> {

    public barProp1: any;
    public barProp2: string;
    public createdDate: Date;
}

public class ConfiService {

    public getConfig<T>() : T {

    }
}
```

and I would use this in my components like:

```
let config = this.configService.getConfig<StyleProps2>()
```

my problem is that my data is all coming from an api and the classes are not simple primitive data types. They have arrays and classes in them (in particular Date), and since the default deserialization does not make those methods available. I researched a bunch of deserialization tools for typescript but none of them worked with generics. How can I deserialize (deeply) my classes and their children?

Comment: You’re talking about complex parsing if you want dates and whatever, you just need to write the deserialization yourself